# Find your dog's age

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

## Task

Take the (integer) number of human years that the dog has lived, \$n\$, as input and return its age in dog years, \$d\$, to two decimal places.
The number of human years, \$n\$, will be between \$1\$ and \$122\$ inclusive: \$n \in [1,122], n \in \Bbb{N}\$.

According to [BBC's Science Focus Magazine](https://www.sciencefocus.com/news/new-trick-to-calculate-your-old-dogs-age/), the correct function for determining your dog's age is:
$$
n = 16 \times \ln(d) + 31
$$
Where

*\$n\$ is the age in human years*

*\$d\$ is the age in dog years*

## Rules

The final output in dog years must be a decimal, **rounded to 2 decimal places.**

Comment: Which range of human years are we supposed to support accurately?

Comment: Is 'rounded to 2 digits' a firm rule? Neither of the current answers do this.

Comment: Yes, it's a firm rule.

Comment: At 969 years, floating point imprecision becomes significant (the correct answer is `28874468684703116351749853` point something, while a simple calculation with doubles returns `28874468684703116489129984.00`. Are you sure you want to set the upper limit to such a high value?

Comment: Ok, I set the max age to 122, which keeps the maximum age to 295.15. Thanks!

Comment: Does "rounded to 2 digits" mean two decimal places or two significant figures? (I don't think this adds anything to the challenge either way.)

Comment: It means two decimal places. I'll specify that.

Comment: ...also I imagine trailing zeros may be implicit, right? (i.e. that `0.5` is an acceptable output when given an input of `20` [rather than `0.50`])

Comment: Are we allowed to assume `n` is an integer?

Comment: Yes. Definitely.

Comment: Many solutions seem to have the logic backwards, giving answers `d` much less than `n`. Unless I missed something

Comment: This question misinterprets the formula. `n` and `d` are the wrong way around. From the [source paper](https://www.cell.com/cell-systems/fulltext/S2405-4712(20)30203-9): _(equivalent) human_age = 16 ln(dog_age) + 31_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Orst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Orst-Geo), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Orst-Geo/wiki/Code-Page)

```
31FᎽGć2Š
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy8qLvn/39jQ7WHfXvcj7UZHF/y/0Pn/v4nBv/yCksz8vOL/ujkA)

As bytes, this is

```
F3 F1 1B FF 30 1C 64 F2 42
```

Or, encoded as UTF-8,

```
óñÿ0dòB
```

which can be run by omitting the `-u` flag (filled by default on TIO). Note the not shown `0x1b` and `0x1c` bytes

### How it works

```
31FᎽGć2Š - Full program. n is pushed to the stack
31       - Push 31
  F      - Subtract; n-31
   Ꮍ     - Push 16
    G    - Divide; (n-31)÷16
     ć   - Exp; exp((n-31)÷16)
      2Š - Round to 2 decimal places
```

Comment: Just curious: What's with the "undefined bytes?"

Comment: @Makonede Orst uses a 512 byte code byte, using a continuation byte (`FF`). When adding Orst to TIO, it was easier to use "undefined" than try to add in a special byte-counting script

Answer (score 5):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 114 bytes

While you all are enjoying rounding built-ins in your language, Io doesn't have any of those convenient rounding built-ins...

```
method(x,I :=((((x-31)/16)exp*100)round asString);I=if(I size<3,"0","").. I;I asMutable atInsertSeq(I size-2,"."))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcyxDsIgFIXh3ae4YeIaitAmDtY@AINTV5eagpJUqEAT4ssjJiae7Uv@HOuLgdMA1/LU6eFnmpmqpnW56SQe5BF1XvdSCAx@czNMcUzBujv2arCGKoj2rc8dI4IwQpBzUL2q1WVL023RMCXlog5p1K9f3LSMcIJYDJUtwlrf0uJ2X/1ZPg)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>36</s> 31 bytes

```perl
printf"%.2f",1.0644944**($_-31)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1JVc8oTUnHUM/AzMTE0sRES0tDJV7X2FDz/39To3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA)

Command line one-liner examples:

```perl
echo 52 | perl -ne 'printf"%.2f\n",2.71828**(($_-31)/16)'
echo 52 | perl -ne 'printf"%.2f\n",1.06449445**($_-31)'
echo 52 | perl -ne 'printf"%.2f",1.06449445**($_-31)'
echo 52 | perl -ne 'printf"%.2f",1.0644944**($_-31)'

for a in {1..122};do echo "Man: $a Dog: "`echo $a|perl -ne'printf"%.2f\n",1.0644944**($_-31)'`;done
```

Comment: `printf"%.2f\n",1.06449445**($_-31)` saves two.

Comment: Do you need the `\n`? (You can only take one input at a time without it, but there's nothing wrong with that.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks, and I also see that for the range 0-125 then 1.06449445 can be shortened to 1.0644944 and still give the same results when rounding to 2 decimals.

Comment: Thanks to @Dingus also.

Comment: 1.0644944 = 2.7182818284**(1/16) = e^(1/16) = sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(e))))

Comment: @KjetilS. Ah, I only tried the rounded value of `1.0644945` good spot.

Comment: Why use the constant?  `exp(($_-31)/16)` is actually shorter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1JVc8oTUkntaJAQ0MlXtfYUFPf0Ezz/39To3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Shorter yet: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1JVc8oTUkntaJAJV7f0EzX2BBI/v9vavQvv6AkMz@v@L9uHgA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-pag)

```
_31÷⁴Æeær2
```

A monadic Link accepting a float which yields a float. (As a full program a decimal input causes the result to be printed.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/e2PDw9keNWw63pR5eVmT0//9/EwMA)**

#### How?

```
_31÷⁴Æeær2 - Link: float, n
 31        - 31
_          - subtract         -> n-31
    ⁴      - 16
   ÷       - divide           -> (n-31)/16
     Æe    - exp(x)           -> exp((n-31)/16)
         2 - 2
       ær  - round to 10^(-y) -> round(exp((n-31)/16), 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Integral](https://github.com/nph278/integral), <s>14</s> 11 Bytes

My first Integral answer!

```
x▼◄w‼5*↕u*‼
```

[Try it!](https://a-ee.github.io/integral/?code=eB8RdxM1KhJ1KhM&input=MTI)

An alternative: [`▲w‼!◄5*↕u*‼` (11 bytes)](https://a-ee.github.io/integral/?code=HncTIRE1KhJ1KhM&input=ICAgICAgICA)

### Explanation

```
x              Push 32
 ▼             x-1
  ◄            Subtraction
   w           Push 16
    ‼          Divide
     5         e ^ a
      *        100
       ↕       Multiplicaiton
        u      Round to the closest integer
         *     100
          ‼    Division
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 13 bytes

Prompts for input of n:

```
⍎2⍕*(⎕-31)÷16
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4/6u0zetQ7VUsDKK5rbKh5eLuh2X@gzP80LkMjIy4uAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 23 bytes

```
31-16/W∆ehS\.€ḣh2wi\.$W
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=31-16%2FW%E2%88%86ehS%5C.%E2%82%AC%E1%B8%A3h2wi%5C.%24W&inputs=40&header=&footer=)

From this answer two stupid features of Vyxal:

- Why \$ln(x)^{-1}\$ needs to take a list instead of digit?
- Seriously it cannot round a digit to n decimal places, so that part is handrolled.

Comment: y'know, there's nicer and more direct ways of asking for feature requests ;p

Comment: @lyxal I'll refer to the Vyxal room as soon as possible (tomorrow)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```javascript
a=>Math.exp(-~a/16-2).toFixed(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/0dbON7EkQy@1okBDty5R39BM10hTryTfLbMiNUXDSPO/dXJ@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGoZGmpvV/AA)

***Thanks to @my pronoun is monicareinstate for -1 byte***

Comment: [32 bytes with the same golf as I proposed for the C answer](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/0dbON7EkQy@1okBDty5R39BM10hTryTfLbMiNUXDSPO/dXJ@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGoZGmpvV/AA "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>35</s> <s>44</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [my pronoun is monicareinstate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/my-pronoun-is-monicareinstate)!!!
Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!
Added 10 bytes to fix a bug kindly pointed out by [Kjetil S](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64733/kjetil-s).

```c
f(n){printf("%.2f",exp(-~n/16.-2));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zuqAoM68kTUNJVc8oTUkntaJAQ7cuT9/QTE/XSFPTuvZ/bmJmnoamQjWXAgikaRgaaVpz1f7/l5yWk5he/F83JxcA)

Comment: Rounding should be inside function f?

Comment: Ignoring rounding, which should be added, [34 bytes (assuming I didn't make a dumb mistake)](https://tio.run/##DctBCoAgEADAe68QIXAhizx06StdRNwQdAszCKSe3tbcx@nVOWaMmy0CFUHNvpyZhL92pR8axqnXBuabkw2kQNRG/PYcqKCSbW9wIdn9dTQAc3Pz6zDa9WAd0wc "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @KjetilS. Oops, missed that - fixed! :-)

Comment: Do you really need the `\n`?

Comment: @Arnauld Of course not - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>52</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

Saved a whopping <s>16</s> 17 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!!!

```python
lambda n:round(1.0644944**(n-31),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqii/NC9Fw1DPwMzExNLEREtLI0/X2FBTx0jzf0FRZl6JRpqGoZGm5n8A)

Comment: @petStorm I disagree, "The final output in dog years must be a decimal, rounded to 2 digits." states nothing about necessitating trailing zeros (and that's assuming it means 2dp rather than 2sf). Furthermore, many answers will give no trailing zero, e.g. `0.5` when given `20`.

Comment: `lambda n:round(math.exp(-~n/16-2),2)` saves 4

Comment: If we can't assume `n` is an integer we can't use `~`; if we can assume `n` is an integer (in \$[1,122]\$) we can do `lambda n:round(2.71828**((n-31)/16),2)` for 38.

Comment: ...actually,  `lambda n:round(1.06449445**(n-31),2)` would work for 36.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh wow, that's great - thanks! :D

Comment: `1.0644944` works too!

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 24 bytes

```
:b$)/100
:R100*x_+$/16-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/3ypJRVPf0MCAyyoISGpVxGur6Bua6Rr9/29sCAA)

For some reason, rounding works on the whole line. I would do `/100/R100*`, but floats went all `9`y on me.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
round(exp((scan()-31)/16),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi/NC9FI7WiQEOjODkxT0NT19hQU9/QTFPHSPO/IZepEZehkeF/AA)

There seems to be some controversy about whether trailing zeros must be printed.
If so, the following 35 byte solution works:

```r
sprintf("%.2f",exp((scan()-31)/16))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), 40 bytes

```
scale=2
define f(n){return e((n-31)/16)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0r@/784OTEn1daIKyU1LTMvVSFNI0@zuii1pLQoTyFVQyNP19hQU9/QTLP2f5qGoZEm1/9/@QUlmfl5xf91cwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <sup><s>12</s></sup> 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

-1 byte thanks to @Shaggy

```
Me°U/G-2 x2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=TWWwVS9HLTIgeDI&input=MTI)

### Explanation

```
Me°U/G-2 x2
Me            //  exp(
  °U          //      (U + 1)
    /G-2      //              / 16 - 2
              //  )
          x2  //  round to 2 decimal digits
```

Comment: `16` can be `G`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
﹪%.2fＸ¹·⁰⁶⁴⁴⁹⁴⁴⁵⁻Ｎ³¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3P6U0J19DSVXPKE1JRyEgvzy1SMNQz8DMxMTSxMRUR8E3M6@0WMMzr6C0xK80Nwkoq6mjYGyoCQTW//@bmP/XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Numeric constant stolen from @JonathanAllan. Explanation:

```
                Ｎ      Input as a number
               ⁻ ³¹    Subtract literal 31
     Ｘ¹·⁰⁶⁴⁴⁹⁴⁴⁵        Raise literal 1.06449445 to that power
﹪%.2f                   Format using literal format string `%.2f`
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
T-☻/e▬♪*i♂‼/%5≥+♀∩*
```

If only MathGolf had a round builtin.. :/
6 bytes are used for the actual formula, 13 for rounding to 2 decimals, haha.

I/O both as a float.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z9E99GM3fqpj6ateTRzlVbmo5lNjxr26KuaPupcqv1oZsOjjpVa//8b6BlwGYIwiGECIkzBQgZg0shIzwAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
T-            # Subtract 31 from the (implicit) input-float
              #  i.e. 50.0 → 19.0
  ☻/          # Divide it by 16
              #  → 1.1875
    e▬        # Push 2.718281828459045 to the power this value
              #  → 3.2788737679386735
♪*            # Multiply it by 1000
              #  → 3278.8737679386735
  i           # Convert it to an integer, truncating the decimal values
              #  → 3278
   ♂          # Push 10
    ‼         # Apply the following two commands separated to the stack:
     /        #  Integer-division
      %       #  Modulo
              #   → 327 and 8
       5≥     # Check if the modulo-10 result (the last digit) is >= 5
              # (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
              #   → 327 and 1
         +    # Add that to the division-by-10 result
              #   → 328
          ♀∩  # Push 1/100
            * # Multiply that to the integer
              #   → 3.28
              # (note: `♀/` cannot be used, because it would act as integer division)
              # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```
|n|print!("{:.2}",((n-31.)/16.).exp())
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RY3BCoMwEETv@YrR0y5oirb0oNWj/yHUUKHdSkxpQfPtaRRKT8Mwu@/Z1@yCETz6UYixKMANs6OwyjrZUVxC6VLp0qcZkeTHQvOhOGvWw2ci5gBwrbxSEbH9XbqWTIWO1fs22CHSutiEzPnEyFsQq01hnhaCUVBo3RRluXuBn1DQYPEZrjHTDBIV22xI0M/YWPX//i4J7d0rH74)

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, 50 bytes

```bash
zmodload zsh/mathfunc
printf %.2f $[16*log($1)+31]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##VYw9b4MwFEV3/4onQSWTyhgb0qgRUqZ269KMEQOyzYdqMMJGBKL8dho6pGJ590nn3jPbapETDm7L3BipTS5hthVtclcVQytQ19etK@Al5AX4F/a206bEPgteY5YtXpqm/g1/BT7GGxQE3i48ne5IicqgO5ITMABPXTslHMQRHKFTPVxYtqLkH@35FjH@RIfnimcIefD98Xl@xKMIlXOdPVI6jmNoRa1aoQojBhsK09BWjXY9xPW1@CHOEJFrMejcKTKZoSdGSyJNaUleKroa@dYolNZ/pvUhdrJONZYWg9ZOXR098yTak@TAOOZREEc8isn78gs)

Gives "dog years" per the **original** refs and examples. For example, the "[ScienceFocus](https://www.sciencefocus.com/news/new-trick-to-calculate-your-old-dogs-age/)" article gives 2 examples, and the "[Cell Systems](https://www.cell.com/cell-systems/fulltext/S2405-4712(20)30203-9)" paper gives 1 example, as tabulated:
     <sub>**`dog age | equivalent human age`**

**`actual years | approx. "dog years"`** 

           `1 | ~30`                 

           `4 | ~52`                 

          `12 | ~70`</sub>

Do programmers ever read requirements?

Comment: This was my first question, and I wrote it in a bit of a hurry, so it is bad and not very well researched. Thanks for the help, and nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
>16/Ížrsm2.ò
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fztBM/3Dv0X1FxblGeoc3/f9vaGQEAA)

```
>16/Ížrsm2.ò  # full program
          .ò  # round...
     žr       # 2.718281828459045...
       sm     # to the power of...
              # implicit input...
>             # plus 1...
   /          # divided by...
 16           # literal...
    Í         # minus 2...
          .ò  # to...
         2    # literal...
          .ò  # decimal places
              # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### HP‑41C series, 18 B

You must place \$n\$ on top of the stack first (a. k. a. the `X` register).
Then you can `XEQ` (execute) the following program:

```
01♦LBL "Y"         5 Bytes    global label requires 4 + (length of string) Bytes
   NULL            1 Byte     invisible Null byte before numbers
02 31              2 Bytes    X ≔ 31;  Y ≔ 
03 −               1 Byte     X ≔  − 31
   NULL            1 Byte     invisible Null byte before numbers
04 16              2 Bytes    place the value 16 on top of the stack; X ≔ 16
05 ∕               1 Byte     X ≔ ( − 31) ∕ 16
06 E↑X             1 Byte      raised to the power of X
07 FIX 2           2 Bytes    show (up to) two place after the radix point
08 RND             1 Byte     round the value
09 RTN             1 Byte     `RTN` does not affect local label search
```

The fixed decimal point display is always rounded.
However, the display settings do not affect the internally stored numbers.
To ensure all digits *after* the second decimal place are zero, too, `RND` (round) is applied.